# add to PriorityQueue<Integer>

Tags: java, queue, priority-queue

For this:

```
    PriorityQueue<Integer> pq = new PriorityQueue<>();
    pq.add(2);
    System.out.println(pq);
    pq.add(4);
    System.out.println(pq);
    pq.add(1);
    System.out.println(pq);
```

I am getting this output:

```
[2]
[2, 4]
[1, 4, 2]
```

Why is the output for the third line not `[2,4,1]` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nowhere it's written that the `toString` implementation for `PriorityQueue` returns them in order. Actually the problem is that:

- `PriorityQueue` doesn't provide a `toString()` implementation, so `AbstractCollection::toString()` is used.
- `AbstractCollection::toString()` prints items by using `iterator()` method (so by calling `next()` and `hasNext()`)
- the documentation about `PriorityQueue::iterator` states: *Returns an iterator over the elements in this queue. The iterator does not return the elements in any particular order.*

So basically `toString` relies on `iterator()` which doesn't provide an ordered view of the elements.